# How MUI control clicking outside of a component, the component itself will close?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm learning `MUI` 5 component design. Can anyone tell me where is the logic that control clicking outside of a component, the component itself will close?

I couldn't find it from the souce code.

It has applied on `select` component and `dialog` component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a component called `ClickAwayListener` available to handleOutSideClick, you need to wrap your `select` or `dialog` component into it.

You just need to pass a function to a prop called `onClickAway` to the `ClickAwayListener` component to handle the case when clicking outside.

here is a [demo example](https://codesandbox.io/s/s5624o?file=/demo.js:557-568) of it from MUI's [official document](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-click-away-listener/).

Answer (score 1):

The Menu component has onClose callback fired when you click away. Use it to change the open state of your menu.

```
    <Menu
      onClose={handleClose} // here
      anchorEl={anchorEl}
      open={open}
    />
```

Answer (score -1):

we can use **ClickAwayListener** component to wrape the actual compoenent in the following way and disable when we click outside of actual component.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Paper, Box, ClickAwayListener } from '@mui/material'


export default function ClickAway() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false)

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen((prev) => !prev)
  }

  const handleClickAway = () => {
    setOpen(false)
  }

  const styles = {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 28,
    right: 0,
    left: 0,
    zIndex: 1,
    border: '1px solid',
    p: 1,
    bgcolor: 'background.paper',
  }

  return (
    <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClickAway}>
      <Paper sx={{ position: 'relative' }}>
        <button type='button' onClick={handleClick}>
          Open menu dropdown
        </button>
        {open ? (
          <Box sx={styles}>
            Click me, I will stay visible until you click outside.
          </Box>
        ) : null}
      </Paper>
    </ClickAwayListener>
  )
}
```